Yehoshua bin Nun and Yosef
In Sefer Yehoshua chapter 24 it says that Yehoshua lived to be 110 years old, Yosef also lived to be 110 years old. Also Yosef's burial follows Yehoshua's burial. Is there any significance to this?

Note that according to the Midrash, they were both supposed to live 120 years, and they both lost 10 years, each for their own reason.

@Sholom what was Yosef’s reason?

@CuriousYid for not protesting when the brothers referred to his father Ya’akov as “your servant” ten times when speaking to him.

Do you mean in addition to being a descendant of Yosef?

There are connections from the kabbalah seforim. Seder haDoros brings a quote from Gilgulei haNeshamos:

יהושע להיותו גלגול יוסף שלא לקח אשת אדוניו לקח עתה את רחב גלגולה ובהיותה מבחינת ירח לכן היה ביריחו (ג"נ אות מ')
Yehoshua was Gilgul of Yosef, who did not marry a wife of his master (Potifar), rather he married Rachav - her gilgul, and since she was compared to New Moon (yerach), she resided in Yericho.

Now, this comparison to a new moon actually comes from blessings of Yosef as discussed by Tzror haMor on Bereshis 30:22, who finds connection between 7 blessings of Yosef, 7 blessings of groom and bride (compared to Sun and Moon), (and also 7 blessings on matza).

אנו מברכין לבנות ישראל ז' ברכות לכבוד חתן וכלה שהם כנגד שמש וירח. וזהו וממגד תבואות שמש וממגד גרש ירחים.
We bless daughters of Israel with 7 blessings to honor groom and bride who are like Sun and Moon, and that is from blessing of Yosef (Devarim 33:14)
With the bounteous yield of the sun, And the bounteous crop of the moons;

